# Synchronizing transform transitions on multiple elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, css-animations, round-slider

I am using a slider plugin (http://roundsliderui.com/) and added additional elements to have a custom fill image. In Chrome, the transitions that happen when the slider is clicked are not synchronized even though the settings are the same. It only seems to happen in Chrome, and is worse on mobile. I am targeting Android with the Crosswalk webview, so it will affect all users, especially slower phones.

The plugin has one element that rotates the handle, and I add one child to clip the fill image (`.rs-range-clip-custom`, no transform) with a child that rotates back to vertical to hold the fill image as a background (`.rs-range-custom`). It is very noticeable for the actual images, since the fill will either leave a gap at the end or extend past the end of the track depending on the direction it is moving.

```
.rs-animation .rs-transition {/* plugin css */
    transition: all .5s linear 0s;
}
.rs-animation .rs-range-custom {/* my css */
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
```

You can view a simplified version of the slider at http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/XjbaWR

How can I ensure the two animations are synchronized?

Comment: Here can't get your exact requirement.. what is the purpose you are adding additional elements and what is your final goal ?

Comment: I want a custom image as the range/fill background instead of a solid color. It should stay static and be clipped instead of rotating with the handle. If you look at the codepen, I set a static background image as the track, another for the handle, and a third for the range fill

Answer (score 0):

Here i have customized the [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) in sample level to achieve your requirement.

In the below demo i have added an additional SVG element as range to apply the image for that. Please check the below demo, which demonstrate your requirement:

### http://jsbin.com/debiyu/edit?html,output

For better understanding I have applied some other png images in the below demo, check that:

### http://jsbin.com/henola/1/edit?html,output

From here you can customize further based on your requirement. I hope this helps you.. Please let me know your comments.

Comment: That isnt quite what I wanted, but it put me on the right track. I changed the `path` to a `circle`and used `stroke-dasharray` to set the length. It probabaly still has the animation sync issue, but it is mostly hidden by the handle http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/xEWvNv